# Unhiding the navigation bar after popping a UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uipageviewcontroller

I am having trouble trying to unhide the navigation bar in my app. I have a UIPageViewController created in a UIViewController like so:

```
//Hide the bar
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden=YES;

// Create page view controller
    self.pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;


    UIPageControl *pageControl = [UIPageControl appearance];
    pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:229/255.0 green:145/255.0 blue:217/255.0 alpha:1];
    pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];



    //Call our helper method
    StickerContentViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
    //Need to pass the first one, don't put them all in here
    NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];


    self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

    //setup
    [self addChildViewController:_pageViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:_pageViewController.view];
    [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

When I pop the UIViewController (the one containing the UIPageViewController) using `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` I can't get the navigation bar to unhide for the previous screen. I have tried placing `self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=NO;` in the viewWillDisappear, viewDidDissappear. I also tried putting it in the content view controller but still no luck. Could someone give me a pointer to what I might be doing wrong here please?

Comment: Try setting  the navigationbar  hidden =NO in previous screen ViewWIillAppear method .

Comment: Tried that. No luck. My usual pattern for unhiding and hiding is hide the bar in the viewDidLoad method and then unhide in the viewWillDisappear. The UIPageViewController seems to be confusing it though..

Comment: viewWillAppear gets called each time you load viewcontroller so try enabling in this method

Comment: I have done this. Tried placing the code there. Doesn't work though. It does call the code in viewWillAppear (I checked with an NSLog) but for some reason it won't unhide the navigation bar.

Comment: Could it be because of the child/parent view controller setup?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, just posting in case someone else has an issue. I was using `self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden=YES;` when I should have used `self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;`. Not sure what the difference is. Anyway I hide the bar in the viewDidLoad and unhide it in the viewWillDisappear and it works now. thanks guys